# Python - display loading animation while preforming a (long) task

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm trying to implement a program that is able to run functions (which take long time to complete).

My understanding of threads and code-flow in python is quite limited, and I'm having a difficult time understanding how some methods, that can have no explicit *async-await* keywords (e.g. the [PyGithub library](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html), which makes requests and having me wait for results **without** *await*) can work within threads and asyncronous processes.

Here's an example of a program I'm trying to make (not exactly the right implementation):

```py
from asyncio import create_task, sleep

# loading animation
async def loading():
    delay, chars, i = .06, '|/—\\', 0
    while True:
        print(chars[i % len(chars)], end='\r')  # print one char out of <chars[x]> at one instance of time
        i += 1
        await sleep(delay)


# Executing given function while displaying a loading-animation on console
# :param exec: a given function to run while loading (type: (...) -> any).
# :param msgBefore: a message to display before starting the process (type: str).
# :rtype: ReturnType<exec>
async def execWhileLoading(exec, msgBefore):
    # print before-msg
    print(msgBefore)
    # fetch data while loading
    loading_t = create_task(loading())   # load animation on another thread
    result = exec()                      # returns a result after some time (NOT asyncronous)
    # fetching is done - cancel loading animation
    loading_t.cancel()                   # cancel animation thread
    print(' ', end='\r')                 # hide loading-char from console
    return result
```

Here we have 2 simple functions. The `execWhileLoading` function is called whenever we're trying to run something with a nice loading-animation on the console. The `loading` is called as an *async* function, displaying and changing the animation text on screen.

My problem is with the `exec` function. Either normal or async, i can't figure out what should i do in which cases. How can i integrate it correctly so that the exec function is running while the loading function runs as well? It alse should stop when the exec function has resolved (somehow).

Hope my question is clear.

Comment: Does the animation start ?

Comment: Not in a case of a regular function (meaning a non-async one, but still should take long time to execute). This is exactly my problem, how exactly should i approach this problem while knowing that there are functions that aren't necessarily async but i still have to wait for them to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Change one line in your function execWhileLoading to run the loading function in an Executor.  The default executor (a ThreadPoolExecutor) runs the function in another thread, but you may want to use a ProcessPoolExecutor instead.  The method returns an awaitable, so it needs to be used in an await expression.

See the standard library docs here. https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools

And pretty please change the variable name "exec" to something else (`exec` is a built-in function, and using it as a variable name shadows the normal functionality).

```
async def execWhileLoading(func, msgBefore):
    # print before-msg
    print(msgBefore)
    # fetch data while loading
    loading_t = create_task(loading())   # load animation on another thread
    # returns a result after some time (NOT asyncronous)
    result = await asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, func)                                    
    # fetching is done - cancel loading animation
    loading_t.cancel()                   # cancel animation thread
    print(' ', end='\r')                 # hide loading-char from console
    return result
```